# GeoTiff image is read as all zeros in numpy array using gdal

Tags: python, gis, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to read pixel values and coordinates from landsat8 geotiff file but after reading the file as array it is only showing zeros for my geotiff file. I am using following code to read the file :

```
from osgeo import gdal
gtif = gdal.Open( "FileName.TIF" )
band = gtif.GetRasterBand(1)
print(band.ReadAsArray())
```

"FileName.TIF" is one of the band image of Landsat.

I also want to traverse the entire image and get coordinates so please suggest if there is any easy method to traverse the image.
Here is the link of image I am using ::

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SqJ2dQLzqsQFUM61vPWe2u2z_R6Zeqa0
```

Comment: Your syntax seems ok. Are you usre the image is not corrupt?

Comment: Yeah I can read the image in any other image viewer..

Answer (score 1):

The way you read the image seems ok. However you can not validate if the image is all zeros by only printing it. It only prints the corners, hence you will only see zeros since your image has zero values around all corners.

You can validate that some value larger than 0 exists using numpy. Change your code to the following. Notice that now in the end it will print 39935 which is the max value of your raster (and which is not zero)

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
gtif = gdal.Open( "test.tif" )
band = gtif.GetRasterBand(1)
bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
print(bandArray)
print(np.max(bandArray))
```

In order to get the coordinate of a specific pixel you can use the same approach used to get the lower right corner coordinates of a raster.

```
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = gtif.GetGeoTransform()
lrx = ulx + (gtif.RasterXSize * xres)
lry = uly + (gtif.RasterYSize * yres)
```

In the above code `ulx` and `uly` is the coordinates of the upper left corner. This can be extracted directly from the raster. The `xres` and `yres` is the size of each pixel. Given this the lower right corner coordinates `lrx` and `lry` can be calculated from the previous mentioned values.

Now in order to find the coordinate of any pixel within the image, you can simply replace `gtif.RasterXSize` and `gtif.RasterYSize` with the pixel entry you need the coordinate of.

```
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = gtif.GetGeoTransform()
xCoord = ulx + (pixelX * xres)
yCoord = uly + (pixelY * yres)
```

So to traverese it an get each pixel coordinate you could do the following

```
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = gtif.GetGeoTransform()
for x in range(0, gtif.RasterXSize):
  for y in range(0, gtif.RasterYSize):
    xCoord = ulx + (x * xres)
    yCoord = uly + (y * yres)
    # now do something with the coordinate
```

Comment: Thanks I am able to read coordinate now but still first problem is major for me. I need pixel value at each coordinate so I can perform my task on it. I am checking out other stuff online like if this is problem with landsat image or something else. So please suggest me if you have anything in mind related to first problem's solution. Thanks Again.

Comment: Can you give provide a link to the image. I guess it is available on Amazon S3. Further what version of GAL are you using, and is it Anaconda or some other python distribution?

Comment: I am using GDAL version 2.2.2 and I am not using any framework like pycharm/anaconda  I have installed it in inbuilt python3 framework and running my code on jupyter notebook(5.4.0). Here is link to Landsat8 image I am using :   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SqJ2dQLzqsQFUM61vPWe2u2z_R6Zeqa0

Comment: Also to complete the system into I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system.

Comment: I have tested the image and i can read it with no problem.
How have you validated that it is all zeros?
If you only print the array as you do in the code you have, you will only see zeros. However this does not mean it is all zeros. This is due to the shape of the image. As you see you have blacker corners. So everything printed (the corners of the image) is zeros.
I have update the answer with how you should test fror all zeros